# Weird CSS behavior... removing a 1px border makes <DIV> move about 20px

Tags: css, html-parsing

I have the following:

### CSS

```
#pageBody
{
    height: 500px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    /*border: 1px solid #00ff00;*/
}

#pageContent
{
    height:460px;
    margin-left:35px;
    margin-right:35px;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    padding:0px 0 0 0;
}
```

## HTML

```
    <div id="pageBody"> 
    <div id="pageContent"> 
        <p> 
        blah blah blah
        </p> 
    </div> 
    </div>
```

If I uncomment the border line in pageBody, everything fits sweetly... I had the border on to verify things were as expected. But removing the border, pageBody drops down the page about 20px, while pageContent does not appear to move at all.

Now this is not the real page, but a subset. If nothing's obvious I can attempt to generate a working minimal sample, but I thought there might be an easy quick answer first.

I see the same exact problem in Chrome and IE8, suggesting it's me not the browser. Any tips where to look? I wondered maybe the 1px border was some tipping point making the contents of a div just too big, but changing #pageContent height to e.g 400 makes no difference, other than clipping the bottom off that div.

Comment: It sounds like pageBody might be inheriting something from somewhere else...

Comment: I just put this example in a simple web page and didn't experience any oddities.  It worked in IE8, Chrome, and Firefox 3.6.3 as expected.  I used the html 4.0 transitional doctype.

Comment: Did you examine it with Firebug or a similar tool? In most cases, it helps to find strange things like this, by just playing around with the styles and checking how rules are inherited, and result in different layouts.

Comment: User is wondering why on http://jsfiddle.net/5sxh3/1/ red glues to the top, but on http://jsfiddle.net/aq5fT/ red gets centered. The only difference is the border statement.

Comment: I agree with Justin and OregonGhost - you should use Firebug and see if that div is inheriting rules from somewhere else. You can also then change it without reloading the page and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appearently, when you add a border or a margin to the `pageBody`, the top of `pageContent` gets calculated as `pageBody.border` + `pageBody.margin` + `pageContent.margin-top`. Else it seems to ignore the `pageContent.margin-top`.

This is a typical case of [margin collapsing](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing)

Answer (score 3):

Margins are collapsing.
(Visible with giving #pageBody red background and #pageContent blue background.)

That is: since both are block elements and margins are touching, they collapse together and the bigger one stays in effect.
If there is any border or padding between both margins, they aren't adjoining and thus don't collapse.

It's expected behaviour: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `position: relative;` on your div's... I've had that fix similar types of issues before.

Comment: Doesn't any CSS positioning bork IE6?

Comment: Actually quite the contrary... Any time you do a float you have to set a position on it or it will bork IE6.